# cannot find symbol throws IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java

I have the following simple class:

```
public class Polynomial {
    private double[] c;
    public double get(int i) throws IndexOutOfBoundException { return c[i]; }
    public void set(int i, double a) throws IndexOutOfBoundException, ArithmeticException { c[i] = a; }
}
```

When compiling I am getting this error:

```
Polynomial.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    public double get(int i) throws IndexOutOfBoundException { return c[i]; }
                                    ^
  symbol:   class IndexOutOfBoundException
  location: class Polynomial
Polynomial.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
    public void set(int i, double a) throws IndexOutOfBoundException, ArithmeticException { c[i] = a; }
                                            ^
  symbol:   class IndexOutOfBoundException
  location: class Polynomial
2 errors
```

Why am I getting `cannot find symbol` for the exception `IndexOutOfBoundException`? It's been a while since last time I programmed in java but I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: When the compiler complains that it can't find a symbol, *always* check for typos as a first step. Copy the symbol that can't be found, and then use "find" in a context where you think you've got it (e.g. the javadocs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, not `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

You are missing an S